# how extend cutting area in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

i'm cuuting around a photo. now i need extend that area in accordance with the previous cut area.
[image]

as you see the selecting area in before is small and then i need the select area bigger.
is there any way to extend cutting area using a key or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust your selection size via **Select > Transform Selection**

[image]

You can then transform your selection the same as any other object

[image]

Comment: many many thanks. is there any shortcut for fast performing?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  If you use the regular Free Transform shortcut, it will transform what is _inside_ the selection and not the selection itself.